# What does %o mean in apache2 logformat?

Tags: apache, format

in [Apache's logformat doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#custom) : "%...{Foobar}o:  The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the reply"

Do you have an example to show what it means ? What is Foobar?

In the access.log of my company, it is just %o, not %{xxx}o. What does it imply ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o-as-in-output.  %{foo}o is the response header named "foo".
Contrast with %{foo}i -- request header named "foo" (as in "input")

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html:

> Bytes sent, including headers, cannot be zero. You need to enable mod_logio to use this.